# How to make CDI decide the implementation to use according to generic type of the bean

Tags: java, generics, cdi

This is, briefly, my architecture:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to make CDI inject the correct implementation of the BO inside the Controller, and the right implementation of the DAO inside the BO accourding to the generic type of the Controller.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are your _Generic_ classes abstract ? Is your T type resolve in subclass or elsewhere ?

Comment: Only the GenericController.java is abstract because I need to instantiate the generic implementation of the bo and dao at some places, so they cant be abstract, my T type is resolved at the controller and is propagated through the bo and dao..

Comment: Anyway I found a solution and I will be posting it soon

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using an javax.enterprise.inject.Instance object to encapsulate my bo's and dao's. This way:

```
@Inject
private Instance<CrudBO<T>> bo;

public CrudBO<T> getBo() {
    return bo.get();
}
```

Just to make things clear, CrudBO is the interface that GenericCrudBO implements, so,
knowing that by default the GenericCrudBO is annotated with @Default, I annotated the specialized classes with @Alternative:

```
@Alternative
public class SpecializedCrudBO extends GenericCrudBO<SpecificClass>{
}
```

I also declared the alternatives BO's and DAO's in beans.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>com.kichel.marcos.business.SpecializedCrudBO</class>
        ...
    </alternatives>

</beans>
```

And now CDI can handle my generic java beans at runtime, this is very good also because I dont have to create tons of boilerplate classes.